# Multi-Level hovering CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

Trying to work on multi-level hovering, so the premise behind my code is to hover over Linea Pro 4 showing iPod and iPhone, then hover over either iPod or iPhone showing the different types of products, and then hovering over the type of product displaying the part number.

I have tried several CSS variations to get it to work... and I know I have a long way to go, so any starting help would be appreciated... here is my CSS followed by my HTML code

```
CSS CODE

#ipc_cases ul {list-style-type: none; display: inline-block;}
#ipc_cases ul li > ul{display:none; background: rgb(213, 213, 213)}
#ipc_cases ul li ul li > ul {display:none;}
#ipc_cases li:hover > ul{display: inline-block;}

HTML CODE

<div id="ipc_cases">
    <ul>
    <li><a>Linea Pro 4</a>
        <ul>
            <li>iPod
                <ul><li>Rugged Case for LP4-POD4 (iPod) GRAY/BLACK, 1D Scanner No MSR
                         <ul><li>CS-R-LP4-POD4-G/BK</li></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Rugged Case for LP4-POD4 (iPod) GRAY/BLACK, 1D Scanner with MSR
                         <ul><li>CS-RMS-LP4-POD4-G/BK</li></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Rugged Case for LP4C2D-POD4 (iPod) GRAY/BLACK, 2D Scanner No MSR
                         <ul><li>CS-R-LP4C2D-POD4-G/BK</li></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Rugged Case for LP4C2D-POD4 (iPod) GRAY/BLACK, 2D Scanner with MSR
                         <ul><li>CS-RMS-LP4C2D-POD4-G/BK</li></ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>iPhone
                <ul><li>Rugged Case for LP4-PH4 (iPhone) GRAY/BLACK, 1D Scanner No MSR
                         <ul><li>CS-R-LP4-PH4-G/BK</li></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Rugged Case for LP4-PH4 (iPhone) GRAY/BLACK, 1D Scanner with MSR
                         <ul><li>CS-RMS-LP4-PH4-G/BK</li></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Rugged Case for LP4C2D-PH4 (iPhone) GRAY/BLACK, 2D Scanner No MSR
                         <ul><li>CS-R-LP4C2D-PH4-G/BK</li></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Rugged Case for LP4C2D-PH4 (iPhone) GRAY/BLACK, 2D Scanner with MSR
                         <ul><li>CS-RMS-LP4C2D-PH4-G/BK</li></ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your 3rd line of CSS should say `#ipc_cases` not `#ipc_case`.

Comment: I edited my CSS code... That works the way I want it to, but I feel like I came to that by luck... can you explain it to me a little bit?

Comment: Quite simply you don't have an id called `#ip_case`, so that rule won't be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It should work](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/UFvhg/) the way you want if you use a [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) between the `li:hover` and `ul` in that final selector:

```
#ipc_cases li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Previously, with out the child combinator, `li:hover ul` was expanding all of the descendants, which is what caused everything to show up when you hovered on the first level. By using the child combinator, each hovered `li` only reveals the `ul`s that are directly below it in the DOM.

Comment: So, just to be sure I understand this properly... For every 'li' that I have (no matter how deep) if I hover over it only it's child will be shown?

Comment: Yes. Without the child combinator the whitespace between `li:hover` and `ul` is a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators), which means that it will match any `ul` inside of `li:hover`, no matter how deep. The child combinator restricts it to direct children.

Comment: so now my next issue is how can I get it so that when I hover over iPod, iPhone isn't dropped down below the iPod information and all the hovering brings up things to the right

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you want iPhone to be hidden when you hover over iPod? What do you mean by "all the hovering brings up things to the right"?